# "Converting" string to type

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-development, tiled

First of all, I am having a bit of a struggle to explain what I need, so I hope you could understand my explanation.
I am currently writing my own game engine. I have all the basic stuff sorted out and I am starting to integrate my game engine with Tiled as a level editor. In my game engine, all "gameobjects" are made of components that handle different things. The way I have found to define a gameobject through Tiled is to add different string properties, each property has the name of the component and the data needed to construct it. So from the tmx file that Tiled gives me I can get the name of the component and it's data.
However my problem is to use this data in my c++ code. I do have the name of the component, but I can't call it's constructor because I can't "convert" the name to a type. I could have made a gigantic state machine that compare the name of the component and calls the right constructor. But because I want the user to be able to create custom components that become problematic.
I would have liked to do something like a map takes a string as a key and return a type of component as a value, but I am not sure if that possible.
Do anyone know of a way to do something like this? Or at least a way that require as little as possible of manual code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ convert string to typename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127040/c-convert-string-to-typename)

Comment: What you are describing is reflection. C++ does not have such a feature. I think you will have to do the heavy work yourself, maybe with a dynamic list where you register new classes. It's not going to be pretty.